# C# Get Html code from url with parameters

Tags: c#, http, parsing

For example, using this url 
http://www.rzjets.net/aircraft/index.php?registry=F-OLRC&frstatus=1

I want to parse the result page.

I'm using those codes but I have an empty result:

```
            var urlRzjetsNoParameters = "http://www.rzjets.net/aircraft/index.php";
            string result;

            using (var client = new WebClient()) {
                client.QueryString.Add("registry",reg);
                client.QueryString.Add("frstatus","1");
                result = client.DownloadString(urlRzjetsNoParameters);
            }
```

or

```
            var urlRzjets = "http://www.rzjets.net/aircraft/index.php?registry={0}&frstatus=1";
            var url = string.Format(urlRzjets, Uri.EscapeDataString(reg));
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                result = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
```

If you may help me please

Comment: Try adding a user agent with client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"); some websites don't respond anything unless you have a user agent

Comment: Thx, it was the case

Comment: Glad to help :)